# C++ Stacked List push function printing next/previous element

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

I just had a question on printing out the previous value. The code prints out everything fine for when it pushes on top of the stack but when I try to output what was the previous head it just points to a memory address.

```
void linkedListStack::push(int v)
{
    listNode *newNode = new listNode;    
    newNode->value = v;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (top != NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = top;
    }
    top = newNode;
    cout <<"Pushed "<< newNode->value << " onto the top of the stack." << endl;
    cout << "Previous is: " << newNode->next << endl;

}
```

The push function is reading integers from a file and pushing that data onto the stack, but I'm unsure how to get the next/previous value to be printed out.

edit:

```
 newNode->next->value
```

has been tried but is broken, still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newNode->next` is a pointer to the next element in the list. This is naurally a memory address. So,

```
cout << "Previous is: " << newNode->next << endl;
```

prints out the memory address of the next element in the stack. What you needed is the value of the next element. When ever you have a pointer to an object and you need to access something within the object, you use the arrow operator (`->`). So your code should have been:

```
cout << "Previous is: " << newNode->next->value << endl;
```

Also what if there was no next element (Always the case when you insert the first elemnt)? In your case, `newNode->next` would then be `NULL`, leading to undesired result when you first enter the element. So you need to check if it is `NULL`:

```
if (newNode->next != NULL)
{
    cout << "Previous is: " << newNode->next->value << endl;
}
else
{   
    cout << "No previous element" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I have tried newNode->next->value but the output breaks. Could my if statement be causing it to stop right away since at the very beginning the stack is empty and top = null?

Comment: Alright that did the trick. Thanks! I was getting the syntax mixed up when trying to put a nullpointer checker by doing if (!newNode->next = NULL).

Answer (score 1):

If `newNode->value` is the value and if `newNode->next` is the next node, `newNode->next->value` is presumably the value of the next (previous head or `top`) node.

You also can't print the value of the next node, if there isn't any. So do a check:

```
if(newnode->next)
    cout << "Previous is: " << newNode->next->value << endl;
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that I have tried newNode->next->value. But the output breaks right away as it tries to push.

Comment: @user2444400 You should have mentioned that it the question. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Output will break trying to access the new node in the case where it's the first pushed on the stack (you'd be accessing nullptrs). Test for null before trying to print.

Edit: This answer should be taken in conjunction with LogicStuff's advice.